# Printing to console vs to file when measureing access speed

Tags: c

Im working on an assignment to programmatically discover size of cache line on our computer. I know there are commands to find this out. Its not the point.

I have a working example(atleast its showing the results I expect) That essentially

1. initializes a 10000 element int array, which i know is larger than my L1 cache
2. access 1000000 sequential elemnents of that array in spacing of 1,2,4,8...128 adds it to a global variable. I measure the time with a difference of clock_gettime and add at the end get the average access time for each spacing.
3. after loop finishes, the cache is flooded with the values from another array, so you know that the cache does not have any values from the main array prefetched.

   but it only is correct when I print out the time each access takes to the terminal. Doesnt work if I print to a file.

Ive tried creating a dump file where each integer accessed, each time calculation, and the sum are all printed to as they occur. My thought it that this would force compiler to not optimize and calculations out.

Ive tried to randomize the elements of the 10000 element array so they are not optimized out.

Ive tried to start each spacing loop at a random location in the array to reduce possible prefetching.

here is the meat and potatoes of the program full code can be found @ https://gist.github.com/jamesamrundle/7142c2e4fbff1971a7308c771ea65b3f

```
for (i = 1; i <= 128; i=i*2) {
 spacing =  i;
 r = rand()%10000;

 printf("rand = %d",r);
  for (j = 0; j < reps; j++) {
    // printf("arr[ %d ] ",(0 +(j*i)%10000));
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &t1);
    sum = sum +arr1[(r +(j*spacing)%10000)];
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &t2);

    fprintf(xx,"\n\n%d\n",sum);

    d = diff_time(&t1, &t2);
    timeSum += (d-nullTime);
    // timeTotal += (d-nullTime);
    // fprintf ( xx,"%d\n",d);<<<<//UNCOMMENT
    printf ( "*%d*%d\n",p,d); <<<<//COMMENT OUT
// sleep(1);
}
  fprintf (fp, ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>spacing of %d, avg run time = %d \n",spacing,timeSum/reps);
  arrTimes[k] = (timeSum/reps);
  k++;
  timeSum = 0;
  // sum = 0;
randArray();
floodCache(arr1,xx);
  // }
}
```

As is the code takes forever to execute because it prints several million lines to the console.
but when finished you see always a sharp jump when at spacing of 16 elements

> spacing of 1, avg run time = 26
>
> spacing of 2, avg run time = 31
>
> spacing of 4, avg run time = 41
>
> spacing of 8, avg run time = 53
>
> spacing of 16, avg run time = 81 <<<-//16*sizeof(int) = 64, size of my cache line
>
> spacing of 32, avg run time = 83
>
> spacing of 64, avg run time = 86
>
> spacing of 128, avg run time = 91

If you comment out the printf of each array access and replace with the fprintf the average run time is just  always somewhere under 30.

Comment: The time increases and has a jump with printf. And the time is around 30 for every execution with fprintf?

Comment: `monotonic` does not include I/O time.  Suggest using: `CLOCK_REALTIME`